# Python: functional testing of a web scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, pytest

I am building a web scraper in Python. So far I've been testing it with a real website, but I'd like to have a proper test suite, ideally run via pytest. Any ideas/examples how to do it?

I imagine the test would spin up a mini http server serving a couple of pages (presumably in a separate process), run my scraper by calling one of its API functions, check the results and then shut down the server. What's the easiest way to achieve that?

EDIT: I will describe the specific solution here that I found in case it is useful for somebody (certainly not the moderators who closed the question as too broad without trying to discuss or ask for details, they're not interested).

In my (Python 3) code I was initially using `urllib.request`. After spending some time searching on the internets I found the excellent [`httmock`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httmock), but that library mocks [`requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httmock), it doesn't work with `urllib.request`. So, I reworked my code to use `requests` and then I could happily use `httmock` in my tests. Both `requests` and `httmock` are absolutely brilliant, highly recommended.

Comment: Someone just voted to close the question as "too broad". Why is it too broad and how could it be rephrased to be specific enough?

Comment: I found this question useful but I don't have access to open it ! This question should have more discussion as I also have similar questions as this question yet don't have much answers on web.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to run the majority of your tests against an active server, especially one that you intend to start up and destroy after each test. That will slow down your test suite considerably and will make running tests often more painful. Depending on your scraper's complexity, the test suite ensuring the correctness of its scraping logic can grow quite a bit.

Instead run the core functionality of your scraper against static content that you can quickly load (i.e. cached web pages on disk). Testing `extractImageLinksFromPage(page)` doesn't need a server to feed it the page content, you can just `file.load(pageContent)`.

Test just the HTTP request functionality against a running server.

If you want to have some end-to-end tests (that simulate the way the scraper's user will interact with the scraper), those can use a server too.

There are many ways to get a server that feeds content up and running. The quickest I think has to be one that uses `node`, so google for `node RESTful API`. If you want to stay in the Python world, look up `flask`, it's boilerplate-free for your use case.